# merge all constructor objects into array and than call prototype for all of them

Tags: javascript

So, for sure there is a better way to call prototypes for constructor objects.
Than to call them by name obj.getValue(); obj2.getValue;. Here is example of my code i want to wrap them into array. And the call protoype for all of them at once

```js
function inherits(ctor, superCtor) {
  ctor.super_ = superCtor;
  ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
    constructor: {
      value: ctor,
      enumerable: false,
      writable: true,
      configurable: true
    }
  });
};

var Person = function(name, age, value, arr) {
  this.name = name;
  this.age = age;
  this.value = function() {
    var values = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var valu = values.value;
    return {
      value: this.valu,
    }
  };
  this.arr = [];
}

Person.prototype.getName = function() {
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  var txt = document.createTextNode(this.name + this.age);
  div.appendChild(txt);
  body = document.querySelector('body');
  body.appendChild(div);
}

Person.prototype.getVal = function() {
  this.value();
  this.arr.push(this.value);
}

var Friend = function(name, age, value, arr, love) {
  Friend.super_.call(this, name, age, value);
  this.love = love;
}

inherits(Friend, Person);

Friend.prototype.getLove = function() {
  console.log(this.love);
}

var mainObje = [{
  duka: new Person('nemke', 12),
}, {
  vaske: new Friend('duka', 24, 'huge'),
}, ]

for (i = 0; i < mainObje.length; i++) {
  console.log(mainObje[i]);
  for (var key in mainObje[i]) {
    console.log(key);
  }
}

console.log(typeof mainObje)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "*call prototype*"? What is the expected result?

Comment: @Bergi  
Thanks, think Ii wasn't clear enough, when define new object duka and new object vaske, or any new object. If i want to call prototpye for duka i need to call duka.getName and vaske.getName . But I want to just call once and for both of them something like myObje[i].getName(); Thanks again.

Comment: Your `mainObje` is awkwardly nested, yes, but that has nothing to do with the prototypes or your classes. Just use `console.log(mainObje[i][key].getName())` and (that part) will work.

Comment: You sir are awesome, thanks.